# How to create polyline - SVG

Tags: svg, graphics, line, polyline

I am trying to create this:

[image: img]

polyline in SVG. How would I do that?

Thank for all answers

Answer (score 2):

The image is not very clear. I suppose it's an arc. If you need to create it as a polyline you need to calculate the position of the points and store them in an array. Then you need create the string for the `points` attribute using the points in the `pointsArray`. Finally you need to set the value of the `points` attribute of the polyline. I hope it helps.

```js
var pointsArray = [];
let c = {x:50,y:40},// the center of the arc
r=20;
for (var a = -180; a <= 0; a+=6) {
  var x = c.x + r * Math.cos(a * Math.PI/180);
  var y = c.y + r * Math.sin(a * Math.PI/180);
 pointsArray.push([x,y])
}

let points = "";
pointsArray.forEach(p =>{
points += `${p[0]},${p[1]} `
});

theArc.setAttributeNS(null,"points",points);
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50">
<polyline id="theArc" points="" stroke="black" fill="none" />

</svg>
```